# Gitlab hook on accepting merge request

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to invoke a hook when a merge request is accepted in Gitlab?

We've previously used a post-update hook, however this isn't invoked when a merge request has been accepted

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want but you can detect that a Merge Request is being **requested** in the pre-receive hook as long as you look for the string `Merge branch` in the last commit message

Comment: Have the same question, and I need to read the branch being merged and cancel the merge request sometimes. Looks like webhooks don't even read a response, so webhook is not the way to go...